# AngularJS Replace array of integers with words

Tags: angularjs, arrays, angular-filters

I receive numbers for movie genres from an api. Which means, 1 = Action, 34 = Drama, 22 = Horror .... I want to display the genre names instead of the numbers.

```
{{::movie.genre_ids}}
```

HTML output of movie.genre_ids: `[1,34,22]`

Should look like this: Horror Action Drama... without brackets & numbers

Movies have multiple genres so that has to works too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like just a javascript question. How does angular fit in?

Comment: looking for a angular solution

Comment: Can you format your output so it's more clear, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have something like this on $scope:

```
$scope.genres = [];
$scope.genres[1] = 'Horror';
$scope.genres[34] = 'Action';
$scope.genres[22] = 'Drama';

$scope.movies = [
  {title: 'IT', genres: [1,22]},
  {title: 'Alien', genres: [1,34]}
]
```

You can do something like this in the view

```
<div ng-repeat="movie in movies">
  <b>{{movie.title}}</b>
  <i ng-repeat="genre in movie.genres">{{($index > 0 ? ', ' : '') + genres[genre]}}</i>
</div>
```

To get something like this on the page

**IT** *Horror, Drama*
**Alien** *Horror, Action*

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to format the mapping into the below format,

```
$scope.mapping = {"1": "action", "2": "horror"};
```

You can show the output using the below code.

---

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $filter) {
 $scope.mapping = {"1": "action", "2": "horror"};
  $scope.api = [1,2];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
    <span ng-repeat="x in api">{{mapping[x]}}&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

---

Comment: can i use this inside of my existing main ng-repeat movie list? where would i place {{::movie.genre_ids}} ?

Comment: @KarlHusten Yes provided the variables are defined properly, provide me a simple fiddle with sample data if you are facing issues! like this?  `::mapping[movie.genre_ids]`

Comment: @KarlHusten Check my above comment

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise one static array of object like this

```
var movie.genre=[
    {1:'Horror'},
    {34:'Action'},
    {22:'Drama'},
    {56:'Comedy'},
    .....
]
```

In your html use angular :

```
<span ng-repeat="id in movie.genre_ids">
{{movie.genre[d]}}
</span>
```